# Displaying values with leading zeros

Tags: php

I want to display digits with leading 0s, for values of a single digit, specifically for displaying hours and minutes.

How do I do that in PHP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
str_pad($number, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: is there any similar function in javascript??

Comment: @I Like PHP - No built in function I know of.  Just use the following:

String.prototype.leftPad = function (l, c) { return (l < this.length) ? this: new Array(l - this.length + 1).join(c || '0') + this; }

Example: 
var str = "123";
alert(str.leftPad(5,"0"));  // 00123

Answer (score 0):

Or take a look at the sprintf() function:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Answer (score -1):

Use 
    $val = 1 ;

```
print "0".$val ;
```

Comment: How does that deal with `$minutes = 10`?